# Installing local jar file to maven repo without using command line

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a maven project that I just added some features to and in order to do so I had to add a local jar dependency. I have added this jar file to the lib folder of the project on Github, and I want to make it so anyone who downloads the project off Github can install that jar to their m2 directory without having to use the maven install:install-file command through command line. The POM file has the dependency already but I need a way to programmatically install the jar file when building the snapshot with mvn install.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you add a link to your github project so we can have a look at it?

Comment: Can't it's company private

Comment: Why is the jar dependency not available from a maven repository?

Comment: The jar is for a non-maven project, so I just added it to the lib folder of the current project. I can install it to my m2 directory through the command line but I was hoping that each user wouldn't have to do that when they pull the project off Github.

Comment: The best option would be to deploy the jar to a public or at least company-wide maven repository.

Comment: Can you talk with the provider of the JAR to make it available in Maven Central? Then Maven Central aware build tools can declare a dependency to this JAR.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 0:**

Deploy the jar file to a public or comany-wide maven repository. If the project producing this jar is also a git(hub) project, consider using a service like [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/)

**Option 1:**

Ugly, but could work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>42</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/foo-42.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

**Option 2:**

Even more ugly, but could work even better.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-foo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>com.bar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
                        <version>42</version>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/lib/foo-42.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried this and it was able to build the snapshot, which is a step in the right direction. However, when I try running the snapshot I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when it reaches the part of the code that references the new jar I added.

Comment: How about option 2?

Comment: Option 2 didn't work either. I'll look into this more tomorrow and see if the jar can be added to a company repo. Thank you for the help.